# Javascript to show/hide affects all boxes when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I added a simple Javascript to show/hide boxes, which works correctly, but when I click on show all the boxes open. How to fix?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".header").click(function(){
     $(".contents").toggle();
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.contents{display:none;}
.header{cursor:pointer; user-select:none;}
```

HTML:

`<div class="header">Exemple</div>`
`<div class="contents">Exemple</div>`

I want only that box I clicked to open or close. Thanks

Comment: You need to add the related html codes so that others can analysis it

Comment: Hi.  Added it now, I still don't know how to use the site correctly.

Comment: I still do not see boxes

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply show or hide logic is on box so when you click first need to check that show class exist or not if class not exist then add class to hide the box.

In the opposite if click again then if class exist then remove the class so box will be visible.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I added all the information. CSS: .contents{display:none;}
.header{cursor:pointer; user-select:none;} but if I add two boxes, they all open at the same time.